# Can the Eclipse browser control (embedded IE) be used in a Swing application?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, swt

If so, how can I do this?  What jars would I need to deploy with my swing application?
Converting to an Eclipse SWT application is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWT/Swing and SWT have different event loops. While it is possible to get both event loops going in a single app, I would not recommend it. Many bizzare problems crop up that are difficult to diagnose and fix. But if you are determined to try this, here is a resource that will get you started...

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t60541.html